# ¿Qué es Crashlytics de Fabric y cómo configurarlo para Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-fabric, crahslytics

Cuando entro en el apartado <kbd>Crash Reporting</kbd> de la consola de [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase) leo lo siguiente en la parte superior de la pantalla:

> Crashlytics será la nueva herramienta para informar fallos de
>   Firebase. Pruébala ahora mismo.

**¿Qué es Crashlytics  y cómo configurarlo para una aplicación Android?**

Comment: Recientemente dirigí para la empresa donde trabajo un proyecto para la construcción de una APP por parte de una fábrica de software. Al examinar el codigo (clases, manifest, layouts, demás recursos, etc) halle la referencia en fabric.properties a #Contains API Secret used to validate. Así entendí que el Equipo de desarrollo habia utilizado Crashlytics, herramienta que desconocía. Podrías A.Cedano ampliar tu respuesta, precisando: si para hacer evolucionar la APP construida para mi empresa... se justificaría usar Crashlytics o bastaría Android Studio? Dado que el desarrollo se hizo en Android c

Comment: " justificaría usar Crashlytics o bastaría Android Studio? " Son dos cosas distintas, Crashlytics te ayuda a mejorar y mantener el KPI (Key performance index) de tu aplicación mediante los datos que entrega, incluso te alerta de posibles errores en la aplicación no importando si esta desarrollada en Java / Kotlin / C++. @OsioUribeAndroidStudio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿Qué es Crashlytics?

Regularmente realizamos como desarrolladores una búsqueda de errores antes de liberar a producción nuestras aplicaciones, pero mientras más compleja nuestra aplicación existe mayor probabilidad de encontrar errores, incluso después de haber pasado por un proceso de testing y control de calidad.

`Crashlytics` es una poderosa herramienta que nos informa de fallos en nuestras aplicaciones (sin duda hasta el día de hoy aún más poderosa que la información contenida en Google Console Admin). `Crashlytics` nos proporciona un detalle de los errores que ocurrieron en la aplicación, definiendo la clase, la cantidad de incidencias e incluso la descripción del error. Toda esta información la podemos filtrar por versión, sistema operativo, incidencias, usuarios afectados, etc.

`Crashlytics` se puede usar tanto en iOS como en Android.

Este es un ejemplo de como se reporta información en la consola de administración Fabric - Crashlytics:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Cómo configurarlo para una aplicación Android?

Aunque sabemos que se puede instalar desde Firebase, existe una forma aún más sencilla para configurar [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install)

La forma de instalarlo en Android Studio y de esta manera poder configurarlo en tus proyectos es:

Desde el menú ir a `File` > `Settings`

Si usas MAC

`Android Studio` > `Preferences`

A encontrarnos en esta pantalla hay que buscar e instalar el plugin llamado : `Fabric for Android Studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al estar instalado en Android Studio, puedes configurarlo en tu proyecto, tienes que abrir la opción "Fabric" que se encuentra al lado derecho de tu ventana de desarrollo,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al abrir esta ventana da clic en el botón para iniciar,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

requieres autenticarte,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes que seleccionar el paquete de la aplicación y te ira guiando paso a paso donde agregar las dependencias y la inicialización para tu proyecto, en realidad es muy sencillo y rápido. En ocasiones estos pasos los realiza automáticamente si tu proyecto no es muy complejo.

Comment: Interesante... pero estoy en Mac OS y no veo la opción `Plugins` por ningún lado.

Comment: Estoy adicionando más detalles a mi respuesta, de hecho también tengo MAC es en preferences! :)

Comment: Ohhh ahora sí. Di que hay que buscar e instalar el plugin. Vamos a probar...

Comment: Quité la configuración manual para probar a configurarlo con el plugin y dejó de funcionar. Ahora no envía los reportes de fallos, a pesar de que volví a la configuración manual. Escribí un mensaje al soporte de CL ... ¿A ti te envía los reportes?

Comment: =0 si! mmm, me parece que necesitas acceder nuevamente autenticandote a fabric desde Android Studio. :)

Answer (score 3):

## ¿Qué es?

Crashlytics es una herramienta novedosa e interesante de reporte de fallos.

Según sus [creadores](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics):

> La solución de reporte de fallos más poderosa, pero de peso más
>   ligero. Dedique menos tiempo a la búsqueda y más tiempo para
>   solucionar bloqueos. Nombrado el SDK de rendimiento número 1 en iOS y
>   Android, Crashlytics proporciona información profunda y procesable,
>   incluso la línea exacta de código en la que se estrelló su aplicación.
>
> Si bien Crashlytics le brinda informes de fallas potentes, con un clic
>   adicional puede habilitar análisis en tiempo real que lo ayudarán a
>   comprender lo que sucede en su aplicación. El motor de análisis de
>   Fabric proporciona información sobre sus objetivos principales, como
>   el crecimiento, la retención y el compromiso. Finalmente, análisis que
>   no necesita analizar.

Más abajo de esta afirmación leemos:

Cost: **Free**.

O sea, que es gratis.

---

## ¿Cómo se instala?

### Primero configurar `Firebase Crash Reporting`

Nuestra app debe estar configurada para enviar reportes de error a la consola de Firebase.

Esta configuración de puede hacer de forma manual. Si usamos Android Studio, es mejor usar la herramienta de configuración ofrecida por el IDE, la cual agregará las configuraciones requeridas en los archivos gradle.

Explicaré las dos formas de hacerlo.

#### Configurar `Firebase Crash Reporting` usando Android Studio

1. En AndroidStudio seleccionar la opción **`Tools`** o `Herramientas` y luego seleccionar **`Firebase`**
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Se abrirá el asistente. Entonces seleccionar `Crash Reporting`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer clic, aparecerá en forma de enlace lo siguiente: `Set up Firebase Crash Reporting`. Hacer clic sobre ello y seguir las instrucciones en pantalla.

---

#### Configurar `Firebase Crash Reporting` manualmente

En el archivo `build.gradle` de la carpeta `app`, agregar lo siguiente en el apartado `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {


    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //otras cosas ...
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
}
```

---

### Segundo: Configurar `Crashlytics`

Teniendo configurado `Crash Reporting`, pasamos a instalar `Crashlytics`.

#### 1. Crear una cuenta

Antes que nada debemos tener una cuenta creada, es muy fácil, desde la [página oficial](https://fabric.io/). Si ya la tienes pasa a la etapa 2.

#### 2. Configuración gradle

Configuramos siguiendo las [instrucciones indicadas en la página de instalación](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install).

Pero atención, algunas configuraciones van en el archivo `build.gradle` general y otras van en el archivo `build.gradle` de la aplicación (carpeta app).

a. En el archivo `build.gradle` de la carpeta del proyecto, en el apartado `buildscript`:

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }

      dependencies {
        // Estos documentos usan una versión abierta para que nuestro complemento
        // se puede actualizar rápidamente en respuesta a las actualizaciones de herramientas de Android

        // Recomendamos cambiarlo a la última versión de nuestro registro de cambios:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
      }
    }
```

b. En el archivo `build.gradle` de la carpeta de la aplicación:

```
    // El plugin de Fabric hay que ponerlo después del plugin de Android
    // o sea, después de esta línea: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }


    dependencies {

        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') {
                 transitive = true;
        }
    }
```

#### 3. Configuración de `AndroidManifest.xml`

Al crear nuestra cuenta en Fabric, obtendremos una API KEY que debemos colocar en el Manifest, dentro de la etiqueta `application`. Si en el manifest no tenemos permiso internet, debemos otorgarlo sino, ¿cómo va a enviar los reportes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <application


      <meta-data
          android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
          android:value="AQUI-ESCRIBIRAS-TU-API-KEY"
      />

  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

#### 4. Configuración de la Actividad Principal

Finalmente, le abrimos la puerta a Crashlytics desde la actividad principal de nuestra aplicación. Para ello:

a. Agregamos estos dos import:

```
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
```

b. Creamos una nueva instancia de `Crashlytics` en el método `onCreate` de nuestra actividad principal.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
      // ... resto del código
    }
```

---

### ¿Y ahora qué?

Según la documentación, puedes provocar un error para probarlo. Pero.... al menos en mi caso, `Crashlytics` tardó **cinco días para activarse**. El hecho es que recibirás un mensaje en tu correo cuando esté activado.

Un mensaje con contenido como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando des click en `View Details` quedarás sorprendido. En cuanto lo vi tuve la intuición de estar ante una revolución en el mundo de las Apps.

### Más sorpresas

Cuando tu app falle, Fabric de sorprenderá más todavía. Te avisa por email de la incidencia, diciéndote donde ha ocurrido y con un enlace para verla en tu escritorio de Fabric.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hagas click en `Learn More`, te darás cuenta de que hay un antes y un después de Crashlytics.

Todavía quedan muchas cosas por descubrir.

Comment: y a que se debe la pregunta si la respondiste

Comment: Es totalmente válido @FuriosoJack. Si te quedan dudas puedes leer: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). El objetivo era dar a conocer una herramienta que me parece novedosa e interesante. Puede que tú ya la conocieras, pero me parece que muchos otros programadores no. Si eres tú el que ha votado negativo lo considero injusto, pero cada uno es libre de votar como la parezca. La respuesta supone algo de esfuerzo, como para descalificarla tan fácilmente.

Comment: Me parece estupendo la aclaración, de hecho es muy interesante la herramienta. Saludos