# Determinar Error con mi app android en Google Playstore

Tags: android

He desarrollado una app en android que actualmente se encuentra en producción, en la Google Play Store.

El problema es que a veces al abrila se cierra y sale el mensaje de que mi app se ha detenido. No pasa siempre, otras veces la abro y no da error y la he oprobado en otros dispositivos y eso no ocurre

¿Existe alguna forma de que cuando esto pase quede registrado en algún sitio o que mande una petición post a un servidor? Algo asi como un `try - catch` global

Comment: Si pero la app esta con usuarios reales por lo que no tengo acceso a usar el logcat, solo pasa a veces @Jorgesys

Comment: Entonced revisa en la consola de desarrollo, ahí se registran los errores o anr que suceden en la aplicsción

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para determinar errores en una aplicación Android en desarrollo es indispensable el uso del LogCat; pero en el caso de una aplicación que ha sido subida a la tienda Google Play Store, la opción es la Google Developer Console o [Google Play Console](https://developer.android.com/distribute/console/index.html?hl=es-419)

El módulo especifico para verificar información acerca de errores o bloqueos (ANR) que estan ocurriendo en tu aplicación es [Android Vitals](https://developer.android.com/distribute/console/features.html#android-vitals)

Ve a `Android vitals` > `ANRs & Crashes` > `CRASHES` , aquí puedes filtrar los errores reportados en tu aplicación reportados por días, versiones de sistema operativo, versiones de aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar clic a un elemento puedes ver específicamente el detalle del error, similar a lo mostrado en el LogCat.

[image: Android Vitals]

---

Otra opción robusta para tener información de los errores es mediante el Framework `Crashlytics`, el cual puedes instalar fácilmente en tus aplicaciones:

[¿Qué es Crashlytics de Fabric y cómo configurarlo para Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110391/qu%C3%A9-es-crashlytics-de-fabric-y-c%C3%B3mo-configurarlo-para-android)