# Inhabilitar Crash Reporting

Tags: android, firebase, reporting

Google me aviso que mi app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.v1_4.frasesparaenamorar.com) esta infringiendo politicas de privacidad por recolectar datos sensibles atraves de crash reporting.

La verdad no se a que se debe porque esa app fue creada hace mucho por un programador que ni si quiera me acuerdo de donde salió. No estuve a cargo de eso.

Buscando, encontré esto:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk

Ya agregue el tag meta-data en el Manifest, pero no se donde incluir la segunda linea de código:

```
FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(false);
```

Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias.

Comment: Lee lo que dice [este apartado en la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/#user_privacy). Puede que estés recibiendo ese mensaje porque en el código de la App se está **recopilando y enviando información personal en el reporte de crash** (como direcciones de correo electrónico u otros). Si interesa enviar esa información entonces sí, debes hacer lo que dice Google para pedir la autorización del usuario antes de enviar el reporte. De lo contrario, lo que deberías es revisar el código y quitar de los reportes de crash la info personal que se está enviando.

Comment: Bien gracias. Si si, lei esa parte tambien.. pero en que parte del código estará configurado eso? en que archivo digo.. Ya se que puede ser dificil darme una explicación exacta pero por lo menos para investigar a partir de ahi.

Comment: @JosueRodriguez Revisa todos los registros que se realizan desde tu aplicación evitando registrar datos del usuario:
    FirebaseCrash.log( ......... )

Comment: Josué no hay otra alternativa que buscar esta palabra en todo tu proyecto: `FirebaseCrash` para poder quitar el manejo de datos personales en cualquier eventual reporte de errores. Otra cosa que tendrás que verificar es si no se están reportando errores a través de `Crashlytics Fabric`, el cual está llamado a ser el sucesor del reporte de errores propio que trae Firebase. Quizá sea ocasión para migrar todo a `Fabric`, aprovechando que tendrás que revisar todo el reporte de errores de tu App. Ah, y de paso, puedes crear una `Clase` que maneje el reporte de errores... Así todo sería más fácil.

Comment: Sobre la posibilidad de configurar el reporte de errores a través de `Crashlytics`, te dejo [esta pregunta como referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110391/29967). En las respuestas dadas se explica cómo configurarlo. Quizá más adelante explique en mi respuesta cómo usar una `Clase` para manejar desde ella todos los reportes de errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano busqué en todo el proyecto y lo unico q tengo es esto mira, un archivo xml: https://imgur.com/a/LEKrf. Hay algo mal? Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Si buscaste en todo el proyecto **realmente** y eso es todo lo que arroja, no parece haber ninguna `Activity` de tu proyecto desde la cual se estén enviado reportes. No veo entonces el sentido de la advertencia de Google, a no ser que no hayas buscado en todo tu proyecto. Si el mismo no es demasiado grande, entonces revisa cada `Activity` y cada clase para ver si encuentras algún reporte de errores que envíe datos personales, o revisa la advertencia de Google, para ver si te indica desde dónde está ocurriendo eso.

Comment: Al final le consulte al soporte de Google y me dijeron que esta todo bien con mi app. Que no debía hacer más nada con respecto a eso o.O

Answer (score 1):

**No es necesario deshabilitar [Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/)**, considero que puede ser de ayuda para dar seguimiento al comportamiento de tu aplicación.

Anteriormente no había problema para incluir datos en tu reporte (lo cual era un poco raro) pero ahora debes evitar enviar datos del usuario a tu reporte.

---

> [**Privacidad del usuario**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/#user_privacy) Crash Reporting no recopila
>   información de identificación personal (como nombres, direcciones de
>   correo electrónico o números de teléfono). Los programadores pueden
>   recopilar datos adicionales mediante Crash Reporting con mensajes de
>   registro y de excepción. Los datos recopilados a través de Crash
>   Reporting no deben contener información personal que le permita a
>   Google identificar a un individuo.
>
> A continuación, se muestra un ejemplo de un mensaje de registro que no
>   contiene información de identificación personal:
>
> ```
> FirebaseCrash.log("SQL database failed to initialize");
> Y este es un mensaje que sí contiene información de identificación personal:
> FirebaseCrash.log(user.getEmailAddress() + " purchased product " + product.getID());
> ```

**Revisa todos los registros que se realizan desde tu aplicación, evitando registrar datos del usuario**:

```
FirebaseCrash.log( ......... )
```

Comment: No respondí copiando y pegando la información de la documentación y preferí [dejar el enlace en un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150795/inhabilitar-crash-reporting?noredirect=1#comment282521_150795) porque consideraba que una parte altamente interesante de una posible respuesta a esta pregunta era explicar **cuáles son *«las medidas de ofuscación adecuadas»*** de que se hace mención... en el caso de que realmente se quiera optar por esa posibilidad.