# Capturar errores y enviar la salida directamente desde la aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio

La cuestión es que la aplicación para Android que estoy desarrollando funciona perfectamente en mi teléfono, pero cuando la he probado en otros dispositivos se cierra. Lo que me gustaría saber es como puedo hacer que la aplicación capture el error que la cerró y envíe la salida de este a una dirección de correo electrónico.

Lo que pasa es que desde mi país no tengo acceso a esas herramientas(Firebase Crashlytics, Android vitals), o sea que bloquean esos servicios para mi país (Cuba), pero la razón más fuerte por la que quiero implementar lo que exponía anteriormentes es porque gran parte de las personas que usarán mi aplicacion no estarán conectado la mayor parte del tiempo a internet, pero sin embargo, pidiendoles que envien ese email tengo más oportunidades de que el informe del error me llegue.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Revisa el apartado [ask] para crear una publicación que sea de mayor interés y así encontrar una respuesta a tu pregunta. Comparte lo que has intentado para que puedan ayudarte a resolverlo.

Comment: Si estás trabajando con Android Studio, tienes que fijarte en la barra inferior. Allí encontrarás una opción llamada "Logcat" que es una especie de historial de todo lo que va ocurriendo en tu aplicación. Si se produce un error, te lo marcará con líneas de color color rojo. Puedes copiarlas y pegarlas aquí.

Comment: Eso se hacía en el siglo pasado. Hoy día existen otras opciones como [`Crashlytics`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics?hl=es-419) que son muy fáciles de implementar y que te informan de cualquier error en tiempo real, enviándote además la traza del error completa. Y, si no quieres implementar eso, en Google Play Console hay un apartado que llama **`Android Vitals`** donde puedes ver los errores que han ocurrido entrando en la parte de `Bloqueos`. Allí aparece también una traza del error, el tipo de dispositivo, la fecha en que ocurrió, etc.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que desde mi país no tengo acceso a esas herramientas, o sea que bloquean esos servicios para mi país (Cuba), pero la razón más fuerte por la que quiero implementar lo que exponía anteriormentes es porque gran parte de las personas que usarán mi aplicacion no estarán conectado la mayor parte del tiempo a internet, pero sin embargo, pidiendoles que envien ese email tengo más oportunidades de que el informe del error me llegue.

Answer (score 3):

Hoy día intentar capturar un fallo para luego mandarle un email al desarrollador es un intento de re-inventar la rueda, porque existen mecanismos muy fáciles de implementar para detectar errores en las aplicaciones, incluso en tiempo real.

Para Android existe [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics?hl=es-419)<sup>1</sup> que es un módulo avanzado de manejo y supervisión de errores en tiempo real. Según lo que indiques al implementarlo, te enviará a tu correo electrónico una traza completa del error a tu correo electrónico en el momento que ocurra en cualquiera de los dispositivos que use tu aplicación en cualquier parte del mundo.

Crashlytics es fácil de implementar. En el enlace se explica cómo hacerlo.

Si no quieres usar Crashlytics, en Google Play Console hay también una pestaña llamada **`Android vitals`** que te ayuda a revisar los errores ocurridos en tu aplicación.

Sólo tienes que desplegar las opciones de **`Android Vitals`** y elegir entre las opciones que aparecen `Errores ANR y bloqueos` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se abrirá otra ventana. La mayoría de errores aparecen dentro de la ventana `BLOQUEOS`, en la pestaña `ANRS` (al menos en mi caso) pocas veces aparecen errores.

Aquí estamos en la ventana que se abre al seleccionar **`BLOQUEOS`** (recuadro rojo). En el recuadro verde tienes varias opciones de filtro, y en el recuadro naranja tienes la lista de errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si abres cualquiera de los errores de la lista, verás la traza del error. No es tan detallada como cuando usas Crashlytics, pero te da los detalles básicos del error. Aquí por ejemplo está informando de un NPE en la línea 386 de MixtoActivity:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay más opciones, como por ejemplo, las versiones de Android en que falla, agrupación por modelos de dispositivos, etc.

---

## Notas

1. Para más detalles sobre Crashlytics puedes consultar esta pregunta: [¿Qué es Crashlytics de Fabric y cómo configurarlo para Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110391/29967). Algunas de las respuestas refieren a `Fabric`, pero desde entonces la plataforma ha evolucionado y se integra directamente en `Firebase`.